# Why does this batch file fail for some users?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I have a batch file that copies the most recent version of an access front-end file to the user's C: drive and then opens it from there.

For some users, the copy command causes the batch file to close, and I can't work out what could cause that. The file seems to copy, but the batch file just closes itself without any visible error messages.

I've used Pause to confirm that the failure happens at the Copy step, not the Run or the If.

This is Windows 7, I've tried it with Copy and Xcopy. The users with the issue say it's worked in the past, they all have access to the location being copied from (and to). Mapping the location doesn't seem to make any difference, and UNC paths work for most users so it's not that.
Deleting the existing files in C:\databases doesn't help.

```
if not exist "C:\Databases\" mkdir "C:\Databases"

copy "\\SERVER02\FINOPS\COMMAQR\DIGIHUB\1. Live Version\DIGIHUB v2.5.accdb" "C:\Databases\"

start [the file]
```

For 95%+ of users, the batch file copies the most recent version down and opens the file. For a handful, the batch file reaches the copy step and closes itself.

Does anyone know why this could happen, or alternatives to both Copy and XCopy that might not fail?

Comment: add `pause` after the copy line and see the error cause by it.

Comment: Are you sure that all 100% have access to `"\\SERVER02\FINOPS\COMMAQR\DIGIHUB\1. Live Version"` at the time the script is run? Try `@(PushD "\\SERVER02\FINOPS\COMMAQR\DIGIHUB\1. Live Version" 2> Nul && (Echo(Access OK) || Echo(No access) & Pause` to find out. Also  as your `.accdb` file includes a space in its name, you should use the following as your `Start` command, `Start "" "C:\Databases\DIGIHUB v2.5.accdb"`, where **`""`** is an empty `Title`. Also, if you use `xcopy.exe` or `Robocopy.exe` you could create a possible none existing destination directory at the same time as the copy.